# Definition of PDF-Metadata from macros doesn't work in external .tex file

Tags: hyperref, pdf, external-files, metadata

I have two files. My main tex-file and a file with several definitions (not a .sty-file but another .tex-file).

If I try to set my PDF-metadata from my `\@title`-macros with the `\AtBeginDocument`-command (but defined in the external file), I get some errors like:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `\spacefactor' on input line 14.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `\@m' on input line 14.
```

and my metadata is just "title".
However, if I place the code in my main file, it works as expected. 
A mwe would be as follows:

---

```
% main file
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\input{externalfile.tex}

\title{This is a test}

% WORKS
% \makeatletter
% \hypersetup{
%     pdftitle={\@title}
% }
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

---

```
% external file
\usepackage{hyperref}

% DOESN'T WORK
\AtBeginDocument{
    \makeatletter
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle={\@title}
    }
    \makeatother
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated. However I would like to keep the external file as a .tex file (and don't switch to a .sty-file. If this makes any difference)

Comment: \makeatletter/\makeatother must be outside the \AtBeginDocument.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer! Could you please explain why? As far as I understand, I have to change the catcode of the @-character before processing the macros. That's why I thought it should be at the beginning of the document (and therefore inside the AtBeginDocument-command) and not when I define it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Inside the command the change is too late, tex has already seen the \@title command and set the catcode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What I don’t understand is that some times it works… or not. I have a similar code using `\@ifstar` that needed to be in a `\AtBeginDocument` section, and I’ve just stumbled upon this issue while trying to make a MWE for something else. It works in my full blown document, but not in an MWE. After fiddling a bit around, I’ve realized that it works if I put the code into an .sty file and load it as a package… but again not always. In yet another document, I’ve tried to add my code, and loading as part of a big .sty did not work. Putting the `\makeat` outside always work though.

Comment: @Archange in a package loaded with \usepackage the catcode of @ is letter unless you change that (what you shouldn't).

Comment: So I shouldn’t be using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in .sty files? Because the first one is already the case, and I’m breaking things with the second one? That would explain a lot.